# Geography, Stocks - Excel's rich data types / linked data types

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365, microsoft-excel-2019

In Excel 365 (the full online version), I see there is such functionality:
[image: Rich data types, linked data types in Office 365 (Excel 365) - Stocks, Geography]

Now, I find articles implying that such feature exists in Excel's Desktop version (at least Excel 2019) too:
<sub>https://learning.linkedin.com/blog/productivity-tips/3-new-features-in-excel-2019-that-you-ll-actually-use</sub>  
<sub>https://www.howtoexcel.org/general/data-types/</sub>  
<sub>https://office-watch.com/2019/fix-excel-when-stock-and-geography-data-types-go-missing/</sub>

My organisation admin tells that Desktop versions (2016 and 2019) do not have this functionality.

I am confused. Where is the truth? Is it available in Desktop versions only on some special cases (I have properly logged in to my Office account, it is the same account as for Office 365, so the accounts should be linked somehow, I guess). Or is it that it WAS available, but not anymore?

Comment: I have office 365 desktop version Excel 19 and I can see Stocks and Geography, I'm intrigued now to what these do

Comment: Ive just checked my 2016 & 2019 standard installations and both dont have Data Types but my o365 does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The truth is that these rich data types are only available in Office 365.
The only feature which made it to the Excel 2019 desktop version is
[Filled Maps](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-map-chart-in-excel-f2cfed55-d622-42cd-8ec9-ec8a358b593b).

This was apparently a last-minute commercial decision that caught short some bloggers
that presumed their availability in all Office versions.

I found a trace of the weak excuse given by Microsoft for this decision
in the Strategic Finance magazine articles
[Excel: Stocks Data Type](https://sfmagazine.com/post-entry/january-2019-excel-stocks-data-type/)
and
[Excel: New Geography Data Type](https://sfmagazine.com/post-entry/december-2018-excel-new-geography-data-type/).

Both articles contain similar text:

> As with the new Geography data type, the Stocks data type isn’t supported for customers who purchased Excel 2019 or Excel 2016. *Since the data comes from the internet, you must be an Office 365 subscriber in order to have access to these features.*

I must remark that this excuse seems funny enough, as if only Office 365 can
connect to the internet. But all the same, this is the situation today.